# Jersey Tutorials from Basics

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey 1.8 and the tutorials that I am referring are quiet old. Nothing works. I am referring to the tutorial given [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html)

And get a class not found exception. as per the tutorial I made my Java Class as well as configured my web.xml. It shows me an exception and I am not getting a way to fix this. I would like to have a complete up to date tutorial for Jersey implementation. And if something is better than Jersey for REST implementation please suggest. I have rescently started with REST based web services and would appreciate if you can suggest me where to start from(I am only interested in REST). Below is the code that I wrote and compiled using eclipse.

Hello.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    //This method prints the Plain Text
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello()
    {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    //This is the XML request output

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello()
    {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    //This result is produced if HTML is requested

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHTMLHello()
    {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }

}
```

web.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>RESTFullApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>RESTFullApp</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<!--  <welcome-file-list>-->
<!--    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>-->
<!--    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>-->
<!--    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>-->
<!--    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>-->
<!--    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>-->
<!--    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>-->
<!--  </welcome-file-list>-->
</web-app>
```

Noe the error I get while I try to run is

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet JerseyRESTService threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not exactly following the tutorial. You changed bits here and there without actually understanding what they represents. In this particular case, according to the exception,

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

the following init param is wrong

```xml
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>RESTFullApp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It should refer to the package containing the services. Put your service in a package and specify that in the init param value. Jersey or not, using the default package is always a bad practice.

As to the tutorials, why don't you just read Jersey's own documentation? [Jersey Wiki](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Main) and [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html).

Comment: ok... I kinda got you. One thing that I learn here is that using default package is really bad.. Gotcha!!.. and as most of the people are suggesting me to check out the Jersey User Manual... I ll do the same and then get back.

Comment: @BalusC how can I contact you? I have a proposition :)

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#getting-started). It will pretty much always have the most up-to-date tutorial. As for the error, your web.xml declares that your resources classes will be in a package called "RESTFullApp". 1) That's a peculiar package name, and 2) I don't see a package declaration on your class.

**Edit:** For a working example, you check out my [sample project on github](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/basic-jersey). If you have git and maven, you can clone it and run it with

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp
mvn jetty:run -pl basic-jersey
```

Then visit http://localhost:8080/basic-jersey/rest/test

Comment: but in the tutorials they are using Grizzly container and I am using Apache Tomcat.... is there a problem due to that anyways?

Comment: And I was actually looking for a working sample to start with :)

Comment: Added a link to a working example--runnable in Tomcat--to my answer.

Comment: I dont have much Idea about the Maven Build tool. I am using Ant to build the Java Projects. What differences will it cause and how can I get along with it. Is Maven beneficial than Ant

Comment: For this example, knowing Maven is fairly irrelevant. As long as you can install it--installation is very similar to Ant--just use the given command to run the project.

Comment: But yes, in general, Maven is largely superior to plain Ant for a lot of projects due to its convention-over-configuration approach. Just take a look at [this example's POM](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/blob/master/basic-jersey/pom.xml). That lets you compile, test, package, and run a Jersey webapp. Consider how much work you'd have to do in Ant to get the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan for helping me out through this. :)